# Invoice Date sets to 1 Jan 1970 when set to "Paid"

Tags: magento-1, invoice, payment, date

Does anybody please know why some invoices on Magnento 1 are automatically reverting to 1 Jan 1970 for the purchase date and due payment date when they are set to paid?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Because of wrong date format. this is the default value.

Comment: Check your timezone server config vs your magento timezone config.  Make sure they all match.

Answer (score 0):

I Am also facing the same problem, can some please share if they Know the reason.
Also with this, i am facing issue with the mail, whenever I am updating the comment section and notifying the customer, some time they are getting the blank mail.